# CSS List Vertical Menu on click

Tags: javascript, list, switch-statement

I am very new to javascript. I have set up a page with 2 iframes.

In the left iframe is a vertical menu and in the right iframe is the content to be shown when the list item is clicked.

The content loads in the frame successfully but I am trying to change the background color of the list item when it is clicked.

With the code below is does as I expect with the first two items in the list.However when I click the 'member search' the default case is used and any buttons below this one will not change color.

Does anyone know why?

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script>
function menuClicked(button) {

var Button = button;

switch (Button) {

 case "queue": 

       document.getElementById("queueButton").className = "active";
       document.getElementById("tickerButton").className = "notactive";
       document.getElementById("memberButton").className = "notactive";
       document.getElementById("staffButton").className = "notactive";
       document.getElementById("settingsButton").className = "notactive";
       document.getElementById("reportsButton").className = "notactive";
       document.getElementById("logoutButton").className = "notactive";
        break;

case "ticker":

        document.getElementById("queueButton").className = "notactive";
        document.getElementById("tickerButton").className = "active";
        document.getElementById("memberButton").className = "notactive";
        document.getElementById("staffButton").className = "notactive";
        document.getElementById("settingsButton").className = "notactive";
        document.getElementById("reportsButton").className = "notactive";
        document.getElementById("logoutButton").className = "notactive";
        break;

case "member":


        document.getElementById("queueButton").className = "notactive";
        document.getElementById("tickerButton").className = "notactive";
        document.getElementById("memberButton").className = "active";
        document.getElementById("staffButton").className = "notactive";
        document.getElementById("settingsButton").className = "notactive";
        document.getElementById("reportsButton").className = "notactive";
        document.getElementById("logoutButton").className = "notactive";
        break;   

default:
        document.getElementById("queueButton").className = "active";
        document.getElementById("tickerButton").className = "notactive";
        document.getElementById("memberButton111").className = "notactive";
        document.getElementById("staffButton").className = "notactive";
        document.getElementById("settingsButton").className = "notactive";
        document.getElementById("reportsButton").className = "notactive";
        document.getElementById("logoutButton").className = "notactive";
        break;
}


}
</script>
<style>
body {
    margin: 0;
}


ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #373946;
    position: fixed;
    height: 80%;
    overflow: auto;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #6b6b6b;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Helvetica";
}

li a.active {
    background-color: #dd3a78;
    color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}



div {
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #373946;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="queue" style=" vertical-align: middle;">
<img src="/sms/images/asmlogo.png" height="100" width="100"   >
</div>

<ul>
  <li><a id="queueButton"    href="/sms/frames/piles2.php"  onclick="menuClicked('queue')"    STYLE="text-decoration: none" target="main">Message Queue</a></li>
  <li><a id="tickerButton"   href="/sms/frames/ticker2.php" onclick="menuClicked('ticker')"   STYLE="text-decoration: none" target="main">Message Ticker</a></li>
  <li><a id="memberButton"   href="/sms/frames/piles3.php"  onclick="menuClicked('member')"   STYLE="text-decoration: none" target="main">Member Search</a></li>
  <li><a id="staffButton"    href="/sms/frames/ticker2.php" onclick="menuClicked('staff')"    STYLE="text-decoration: none" target="main">Staff</a></li>
  <li><a id="settingsButton" href="/sms/frames/ticker2.php" onclick="menuClicked('settings')" STYLE="text-decoration: none" target="main">Settings</a></li>
  <li><a id="reportsButton"  href="/sms/frames/ticker2.php" onclick="menuClicked('reports')"  STYLE="text-decoration: none" target="main">Reports</a></li>
  <li><a id="logoutButton"   href="/sms/frames/ticker2.php" onclick="menuClicked('logout')"   STYLE="text-decoration: none" target="main">Log Out</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

Codes on this link:

https://www.asmserver.co.uk/sms/frames/menu2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JavaScript seems sound, if lengthy, but from what I can tell from your preview link, there seems to be something funky going on with non-breaking spaces before your classnames? [I've tested it in Chrome's devtools (see attached)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VB6VQ.png) - the first JS call was using code copied from your JavaScript, the second was done by copying the class name from the HTML element.

Seems like a really weird thing though! Not sure how they'd have gotten included in that - may just be worth going back and rewriting each element ID. It also seems to affect `staffButton`, `reportsButton` and `logoutButton` too.

Hope this helps!

Comment: not sure what was going on there but sorted thanks to you :)

Comment: Who knows - it's definitely one of the weirder edge-cases I've seen! Glad I could help :D Good luck in your coding journey!

Answer (score 0):

I think you suffer from a caching issue. The code itself seems fine, but your browser might not have loaded the edited page.

Try to refresh your page a few times. Use F12 (developer tools) to see if the right code is loaded.

Comment: Hi Rogier, thank you for your reply, I have tried a few hard refreshes and even loaded it up on different machines / devices / browsers and I still have the same issue. Im so confused.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can much shorten this like below.

**Script**
Write these below in your script

```
var resetAll = function() {
    document.getElementById("queueButton").className = "notactive";
    document.getElementById("tickerButton").className = "notactive";
    document.getElementById("memberButton").className = "notactive";
    document.getElementById("staffButton").className = "notactive";
    document.getElementById("settingsButton").className = "notactive";
    document.getElementById("reportsButton").className = "notactive";
    document.getElementById("logoutButton").className = "notactive";
}


var menuClicked = function(button) {
  resetAll();
  button.className = 'active';
}
```

**HTML**

Change all the `onClick` in the `a` tag to look like below

```
<li> <a id="queueButton"    href="/sms/frames/piles2.php"  onclick="menuClicked(this)"    STYLE="text-decoration: none" target="main">Message Queue</a></li>

<li><a id="tickerButton"   href="/sms/frames/ticker2.php" onclick="menuClicked(this)"   STYLE="text-decoration: none" target="main">Message Ticker</a></li>
```

And keep your styles and rest of the html as it is. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that your changing the background through a class, which is unsuppirior to an ID or something like that.

you could try this:

a :active {

like in this tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp

or you could use javascript like this to change the background, since you are changing all the buttons seperatly anyway:

```
document.getElementById("queueButton").style.backgroundColor = "#dd3a78";
```

I hope that solves it.

Comment: Hi Max, i have tried this too but still not wokring, I have edited the question with a jsfiddle if you would be kind enough to take a look :)

Comment: I just watched the fiddle and the first link gets the background color when clicked, and keeps it till another one is clicked. Isnt that what you wanted? you just have to copy it for the other buttons as well, or say that the link clicked gets a background colored: this.style.backgroundColor = "#dd3a78";

Comment: Hi, yes that is what im after but thats not how its working at the moment: http://www.asmserver.co.uk/sms/frames/menu2.html

Comment: according to the console, there is a typo:

Answer (score 0):

According to the console of the link, you have a typo in your code.

```
case "queue": 

   document.getElementById("queueButton").style.backgroundColor = "#dd3a78";
   document.getElementById("tickerButton").style.backgroundColor = "#373946";
   document.getElementById("memberButton").style.backgroundColor = "#373946";
   document.getElementById("staffButton").style.backgroundColor = "#373946";
   document.getElementById("settingsButton").style.backgroundColor = "#373946";
   document.getElementById("reportsButton").style.backgroundColor = "#373946";
   document.getElementById("logoutButton").style.backgroundColor = "#373946";
```

It says that the error is by the line of member, which explains why it ends there. Only I do not see the error myself so if anyone else sees it thats the answer.